# Powershell functions test ping

Tags: powershell

I don't understand why my function don't work and wrote this error

> The script failed due to call depth overflow.
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CallDepthOverflow

my code

```
 $table= @("WIN-BFA8HOP8PUQ","WIN-AFI9HOP5PUQ")
> 
> function testping($table) { for ($i=0; $i -lt $table.lenght; $i++ ) {
> 
> If (Test-Connection $table{$i} -count 1 -quiet) {   Write 'the ping
> work'    }else { write 'the ping dont work' } } testping($table) }
```

Comment: you have a recursive function and have too many levels of recursion. [*grin*] ///// also, WHY are you using recursion for this? a simple loop seems likely to do what you seem to want done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some syntax errors, i.e: to select an item on an array you have to use `[]` not `{}`. You're also calling your function inside the function itself which, makes sense when you need recursion, but I don't see how or why you would need recursion here. Check out the below, this should work fine.

```
$table= @("WIN-BFA8HOP8PUQ","WIN-AFI9HOP5PUQ")
function testping($table) {
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $table.count; $i++ )
    { 
        If (Test-Connection $table[$i] -count 1 -quiet)
        {
            Write-Output 'the ping work'
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Output 'the ping dont work'
        }
    }
}

testping -table $table
```

In addition, a `for` is fine to use but you can also use a `foreach` loop which in this case is much easier to use and does the same job:

```
$table= @("WIN-BFA8HOP8PUQ","WIN-AFI9HOP5PUQ")
function testping($table) {
    foreach ($item in $table)
    { 
        If (Test-Connection $item -count 1 -quiet)
        {
            Write-Output 'the ping work'
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Output 'the ping dont work'
        }
    }
}

testping -table $table
```